# Power traces for switching regulator on PCB

Tags: pcb, switching-regulator, emi-filtering

When designing a PCB that has a switching regulator IC, is it better to have the power traces to the IC wider or narrower?

I read that the general rule of thumb is to keep the traces as short and wide as possible.

However, filters such as PI filter or T filter have in-series inductance to help with the noise. Wouldn't narrower traces, consequently higher inductance, have the same effect as the in-line inductor in the filter, which comes off better than wider traces?

Answer (score 1):

Priorities:

1. When inductance must be low, short wide traces, pours or planes are best, and if vias to ground are used, several vias in parallel reduce inductance. Example: input/output caps, Vin and ground for a buck chip, SW and ground for a boost chip.
2. When inductance doesn't matter much, because the trace is in series with the inductor or with a resistor, then it's okay to make it longer. Especially if that allows using shorter traces for the case above, then it's a good tradeoff.

In the case of a switching regulator the switching node voltage is a square wave so its capacitance to nearby copper must be charged and discharged every time it switches, which results in losses, so it's best to keep the copper area small.

Further reading: the [hot loop](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/layout-for-power-designs-1-hot-loops.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not particularly relevant to EMI.

But keep in mind this is in a very particular respect.

Trace inductance is small enough not to have useful filtering value at switching frequencies.  Exact values depend on the transmission line impedance of the trace, but typical figures are 0.5 to 1 nH per mm of length.  Even a run all the way across a board might only accrue a small fraction of a µH.

Accessible trace impedances on PCB are also not very diverse: tens to about 150 ohms.  These aren't vastly different from the impedance of connected cables, or free space, so you won't get much mismatch attenuation this way.  Not to say this impedance couples directly to space -- common mode (ground loop), E-field (trace as patch antenna), and connector/cable (conducted) mechanisms are far more important -- but more to say, you don't get a huge impact on circuit impedance, in contrast to lumped-element filters which can have impedances from milliohms (large ceramic capacitors) to kilohms (large or high-Q low-C inductors).

EMI is much more concerned with the coupling mechanisms.  Keep ground loops small, and keep ground thick and well-connected.  Keep active switching nodes compact (reduce E-field exposed area).  Avoid transmitting DM ripple/noise onto connectors and cables.

In service of those goals, we might use wide and short traces, to reduce the stray inductance between relevant elements (e.g. switching regulator supply and buck input / boost output bypass cap), but the width of traces leading away from local filtering components is not particularly important, and regular ampacity tends to be dominant.

Mind that a power trace may be routed between multiple capacitors, which can therefore resonate with each other via trace inductance.  (Again, the attenuation due to this might not be significant -- typical resonances are in the single digit MHz, having little to no effect on fundamental ripple.  Maybe helpful for high frequencies, but those should already be handled by local filters.)  Sometimes the inductance reduction by using a wider trace is enough to maintain good damping.  Other times, it might be necessary to distribute capacitors along its length (yes, placing capacitors for seemingly no local purpose!), or to introduce damping explicitly (such as a lossy bulk capacitor).